# Extract and multiple integers from user-input string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to take multiple integer inputs in same line

eg :- input 
        -1 -1
         500 500

so that I can multiply them. I am taking the input in a string from keyboard - then what should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This prints ["5", "66", "7", "8"] if you type a line containing `5 66 7 8` (separated by any whitespace):

```
p $stdin.readline.split
```

To get them multiplied, do something like this:

```
q = 1
$stdin.readline.split.each {|n| q *= n.to_i }
p q
```

Comment: or even

$stdin.readline.split.map{|s| s.to_i }.inject{|p,i| p * i}

or

$stdin.readline.split.inject(1){|p,s| p * s.to_i}

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use `String#scan`:

```
irb> "input -1 -1 500 500".scan(/[+-]?\d+/).map { |str| str.to_i } 
#=> [-1, -1, 500, 500 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array = input.split(' ')
```

or, if you're entering them as command line parameters, just use the ARGV array